# Filtrar dados de uma tabela através de um DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, table

Possuo uma tabela retornando os valores pagos por contribuintes. Porém eu tenho que retornar todos os dados (pois a aplicação soma campo a campo). Até aí esta tudo certo.

Mas para mostrar ao usuário, necessito filtrar a tabela por data (ano), para o usuário visualizar as informações anuais.

Fiz um exemplo estático, utilizando JQuery e está funcionando da forma que eu necessito. O problema é que estou com dificuldades para colocar na View da minha aplicação, com os dados retornados da consulta.

O exemplo funcionando pode ser visto aqui no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/u23d7x5b/).
No exemplo eu uso um select estático, com os valores definidos anteriormente. Porém em minha View eu retorno os valores através de uma `ViewBag`.

No script (filter.js) que estou utilizando, tenho que declarar a `<tr>` com a mesma classe que utilizarei no select.

Retorno dos anos:
Controller:

```
ViewBag.AnoExtrato = previdenciaRepository.Previdencias.Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato)
            .Select(x => x.dtCompetencia.Value.Year).Distinct().ToList();
```

E na view eu chamo o select desta forma:

```
 <select class="filter" style="width:100px">
        @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.AnoExtrato.Count; i++)
        {
            <option value="@ViewBag.AnoExtrato[i]">
                @ViewBag.AnoExtrato[i]
            </option>
        }
    </select>
```

Segue o restante da View, mostrando como é povoado a tabela e realizado as somas que necessito:

```
<table border="1" id="item-list" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">
                    Mês
                </th>
                <th rowspan="2">
                    Remuneração<br />
                    Total R$
                </th>
                <th colspan="4">
                    <p align="center">
                        Contribuinte
                    </p>
                </th>
                <th colspan="4">
                    <p align="center">
                        Município
                    </p>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    %
                </th>
                <th>
                    Mês R$
                </th>
                <th>
                    Ano R$
                </th>
                <th>
                    Acumulado R$
                </th>
                <th>
                    %
                </th>
                <th>
                    Mês R$
                </th>
                <th>
                    Ano R$
                </th>
                <th>
                    Acumulado R$
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            @*Variáveis para somar os totais dos campos*@
            @{
                double totalContribuinte = 0;
                double totalMunicipio = 0;
            }

            @foreach (var item in Model.Previdencia.GroupBy(g => new { g.NmPessoa, g.dtCompetencia.Value.Year }))
            {
                @*Variáveis para somar os totais dos campos por ano*@
                double subtotalContribuinte = 0;
                double subtotalMunicipio = 0;

                foreach (var contribuicoes in item.ToList())
                {
                    @*Realizam as somas dos campos*@
                    subtotalContribuinte += contribuicoes.Contribuinte;
                    totalContribuinte += contribuicoes.Contribuinte;

                    subtotalMunicipio += contribuicoes.BaseCalculo;
                    totalMunicipio += contribuicoes.BaseCalculo;


                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => contribuicoes.dtCompetencia)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => contribuicoes.BaseCalculo)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            11
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => contribuicoes.Contribuinte)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @subtotalContribuinte.ToString("c")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @totalContribuinte.ToString("c")
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            11
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => contribuicoes.BaseCalculo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @subtotalMunicipio.ToString("c")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @totalMunicipio.ToString("c")
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

O Arquivo JS que estou utilizando.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    
    // any time a filter drop-down changes...
    $("select.filter").change(function () {
        var classes = "";
        var description = "";
    
    // collect the selected filters
    $("select.filter").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '*') {
        classes += "." + $(this).val();
        if (description != '') description += ', ';
        description += $.trim($(this).find("option:selected").text()); 
        }
    });
    
    if (classes == "") {
        // if no filters selected, show all items
        $("table.item-list tr").show();
    } else {
        // otherwise, hide everything...
        $("table.item-list tr").hide();
        // then show only the matching items
        rows = $("table.item-list tr" + classes);
        if (rows.size() > 0) {
        rows.show();
        }
    }
    
    // count up the matching items
    if (description != '') {
        description += " (" + $("table.item-list tr:visible").size() + ")";
    }
    
    // print a description of the active filter
    $("#filter-description").html(description);
    }).change(); // here in case a drop-down has been pre-selected
    
    // just a nice little hover effect
    $("table.item-list tr").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass("hover");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
        }
    );
    });
```

Como faço para colocar o  **tr** de cada linha igual o valor selecionado na **@ViewBag.AnoExtrato[i]**?

Esta foi a forma que encontrei de fazer, mas se possuir uma forma melhor que realize a mesma função, estou aberto a sugestões.
Lembrando que não estou preso a componentes, podendo ser JS, Jquery, etc.

### UPDATE

Apenas para deixar funcionando a aplicação, adicionei uma "Gambiarra" e deixei a classe do `<tr>` com uma lista de possíveis anos, deixando assim o **Header** visível.

```
 <tr class="1970  1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986
                1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002
                2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu montei um exemplo bem simples abaixo. Usando PartialView, Ajax.BeginForm() e um pouco só de javascript.

Controller:

```
public class FiltroController : Controller
{
  public List<string> Tabela = new List<string>();
  public List<string> Filtro = new List<string>();

  public FiltroController()
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        Tabela.Add("Nome " + i.ToString());
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        Filtro.Add(i.ToString());
     }
  }
  //
  // GET: /Filtro/

  public ActionResult Index(string filtro)
  {
     ViewBag.Filtro = new SelectList(Filtro);
     if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
     {
        return PartialView("_Index", Tabela.Where(_ => _.EndsWith(filtro)).ToList());
     }
     return View(Tabela);
  }

}
```

Index.cshtml

```
  @model List<string>

  @using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "replaceDiv" }))
  {
     @Html.DropDownList("Filtro", "Selecione")
  }

  <div id="replaceDiv">
     @Html.Partial("_Index", Model)
  </div>

  @section scripts{
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#Filtro").change(function () {
              $(this).closest("form").submit();
           });
        });
     </script>
  }
```

E a partialView:

```
  @model List<string>
  <table class="table table-hover">
     <tbody>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           <tr>
              <td>@item</td>
           </tr>
        }

     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Obs: Eu acho legal desta maneira por questão de performace e o fato de possuir pouco javascript, ah e não se esqueça de adicionar o arquivo

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```